# Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 xaml designer not showing for UWP

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, uwp, xaml-designer

Where disappeared XAML designer for Universal Windows app in Visual Studio 2015 Update1?

[image]

It is working for wpf and window 8.1 apps and XAML designer is enabled in Tools->Option->XAML Designer

Comment: I am having the same problem.  For C#/Universal Window projects created before installing Update 1, the Designer is available and it works just fine.  It is only with projects that I created after installing Update 1 that the XMAL Designer is lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the Target Version to (10.0; Bulid 10240)

[image: Targer versuin]

Comment: Actually, targeting lower windows version by default may bee good idea anyway so people does not need to update windows to run my app.

Comment: It worked for me on Windows 10. The problem was that I was targeting Win10 Build 10586, but I was running Win 10240. After update it worked.

Comment: how to find which windows 10 build I am using ,like 10240 or 10586 ?

Comment: @Noorul Open Start Menu, Type "PC-Info", take a look at "Operating System Build"

Answer (score 4):

See the notification asking to update Windows - [image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Updated windows from windows update as instructed by the VS2015 notification and now it is fixed.

Comment: When I check for updates it says: You device is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using VS2015 on an operating system prior to Windows 10. According to a post on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1298326/no-design-view-for-universal-apps-in-either-blend-or-vs-2015-rc-win8-1-apps-ok), this behaviour is by design. When you're using VS2015 on Windows 8.1, there is no support for design view, you have to upgrade to Windows 10 instead:

> "If you are developing Windows 10 applications, this is by design since the designer requires Windows 10 in-order to show the design surface for UWP applications since we run application code. In Windows 8.1 and Windows 7, you will only get intelliSense. If you want full support for the design tools, you need to develop the application on Windows 10."

Comment: No, I had Windows 10, but lower build that the one that was preselected in visual studio project