# Unhandled error whilst trying to open the XAML designer for a UWP app in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, xaml-designer

When trying to open the XAML designer for a brand new UWP app ([that targets build 10240](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34103782/50447)) I'm seeing an error:

> System.Exception
>   **Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.**
>
> **Windows cannot install package {guid} because this package depends on another package that could not be found. This package requires minimum version 14.0.22929.0 of framework Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug published by CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US to install. Provide the framework along with this package.**
>
> ```
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)  
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
> ```

It's worth noting that the XAML designer for Windows Phone 8.x continues to work correctly. As our [corporate anti-virus is incompatible with build 10586](http://support.kaspersky.co.uk/12392#block1), and this explicitly blocks the 1511 update to build 10586, could this be the cause - if so, other than waiting for Kaspersky to support the current version of Windows 10, is there another way to get the XAML designer for UWP apps working in either Visual Studio 2015, or Blend?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that updating the Visual Studio Android emulator fixes the issue(!)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to install the **Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 10**

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

I had the same issue, after installing the SDK everything is smooth