# XAML Designer not showing up in visual studio version 16.10.2

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2019

XAML designer disappeared after I update visual studio to the latest version (16.10.2)

[image]

Here is the options window
[image]

I check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090719/xaml-designer-not-showing-up) And [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088737/visual-studio-2015-update-1-xaml-designer-not-showing-for-uwp) with no result, I repaired the Visual Studio without any result :(

Any help
Thanks

Comment: You could try View->Designer or press SHIFT+F7 on the keyboard when you have a .xaml file opened in the editor.
If this doesn't work for you, you could try to create a new project or reinstall Visual Studio.
By the way, the WPF XAML Designer is part of the ".NET desktop development" workload. Have you tried to check your installation include this workload?

Answer (score 0):

I have VS 2019 16.10.2 installed too and my XAML designer works fine.

My differences from your screen shot are

- Color Theme = Blue
- Optimize rendering = Unchecked

Please also check these settings
[image]